# How to load image from SD card using Picasso library

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

i need to load images from the Sd card into gridview.
For efficiency i'm using **Picasso** Library

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(images.get(position).getDataPath())
            .resize(96, 96).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.image);
```

I used the following code in the adapter. unfortunately m unable to see any images 
so please can any one help.

**Note**
And also can anyone suggest any efficient image loading library to load the images from the sd card.

**Requirement**
I dont to load the image every time when scrolling. If it is already loaded dont load the image on scrolling

Comment: can you show me how your data path looks like ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To load the file you need to convert it to a uri first

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(images.get(position).getDataPath()));

Picasso.with(activity).load(uri)
            .resize(96, 96).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.image);
```

> Requirement I dont to load the image every time when scrolling. If it
>   is already loaded dont load the image on scrolling

- Picasso is excellent for this

Comment: can you paste how your datapath looks like

Comment: does this image exist on the disk ?

Comment: Great solution indeed.

Comment: I don't get this please help me that what position variable does and images object does.

Answer (score 6):

In Picasso version 2.5.2, you need to pass a File as argument to load method, so the image can be loaded as:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(images.get(position).getDataPath()))
    .resize(96, 96).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.image);
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to create a `new File` because if the path was already obtained from an existing file, there is no need for a new object (want to see the already existing picture in the device).

According to Picasso docs you have to do something like this:
`file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png`

So I used to have:
`/storage/sdcard/Pictures/findyoursport/yoursport_1482358052384.jpeg`

Prepending: `file://` did the trick