# Android Picasso don't show image from SDCARD

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to show and attach image which stored on SD-CARD to image view, I can show image with `setImageBitmap` without any problem but when I try to use `Picasso` that don't show image

```
   final File imageFile = new File(APP.DIR_APP + APP.IMAGE + "/" + channel.get(position).getFileName());
   if (imageFile.isFile() && imageFile.exists()) {
       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       //options.inSampleSize = 8;
       //holder.post_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options));
       Picasso.with(context).load(imageFile).into(holder.post_image);
   }
```

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24097624/5425930

Comment: Try `Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(imageFile).toString()).into(holder.post_image);`

Comment: I had a similar situation when picasso was failing if the image size was really large. For me, the solution was to migrate to Glide.

Comment: @KartikSharma image has small size and Picasso can't show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is correct, but when i use `wrap_content` for width and height of ImageView, i dont see image

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have added the READ permission if you haven't then add this line in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: applicaton has this permission

Answer (score 0):

1. Log your `imageFile` path and check it.
2. Check the `context` that you are passing to `Picasso.with(context)`
3. If everything is ok, chanege your code to:

   ```
   if (imageFile.isFile() && imageFile.exists()) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.fromFile(imageFile)).into(holder.post_image);
   }
   ```